# Mass redirect urls through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I changed the path of some urls and would like to get some help if possible, to create a rule in my .htaccess to redirect them in bulk.

The old url were like this one: https://www.mastersol.gr/**hliakoi-thermosifones-solar**/epilektikoi/mastersol-plus-wifi/product/430-160-2-plus-wifi-mastersol

The new urls are like this one: https://www.mastersol.gr/**iliakoi-thermosifones**/epilektikoi/mastersol-plus-wifi/product/430-160-2-plus-wifi-mastersol

As you can see, I changed only the part /hliakoi-thermosifones-solar/ to /iliakoi-thermosifones/ and I need to 301 redirect all /hliakoi-thermosifones-solar/ urls to /iliakoi-thermosifones/.

Could you help on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task appears to be straight forward: you implement a rule matching only those requests still using the old pattern, capture the stuff following after that token to be changed and redirect (or itnernally rewrite) to a newly assembled URL:

For an external redirection:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/?hliakoi-thermosifones-solar(.*)/?$ https://www.mastersol.gr/hliakoi-thermosifones$1 [R=301,END]
```

For an internal rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/?hliakoi-thermosifones-solar(.*)/?$ /hliakoi-thermosifones$1 [END]
```

If you receive back an http status 500 (internal server error) using those rules then chances are that you are using a very old version of the apache http server and have to use the `[L]` flag instead of the `[END]` flag.

---

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug, they really slow down the http server, often for nothing and they can open pathways to security nightmares. They are only provided for situations where you do *not* have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers).

Comment: Thank you very much for all your very informative answer!